# multicolumn query to a single column subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which generates a list of designations and total amounts in which a person donated too over a year. It looks like this

```
select ad1.adbdesg_name as "Desg_Name",
sum(ag1.agvglst_amt) as "Total_Amt"
from agvglst ag1 INNER JOIN adbdesg ad1 ON ag1.agvglst_desg = ad1.adbdesg_desg
where ag1.agvglst_pidm = 12345
and to_char(ag1.agvglst_gift_date,'YYYYMMDD') >= 20150101
and to_char(ag1.agvglst_gift_date,'YYYYMMDD') <= 20151231
group by ad1.adbdesg_name;
```

Simple Right? And I get correct result like this:

```
Desg_Name                                           Total_Amt
Administrative Council Scholarship End Prin NS (65%)    16.9
Blount County Campus                                     240
Administrative Council Scholarship (35%)                 9.1
Faculty Senate Scholarship                                10
```

My issue is now I need to make this into a single-line subquery to place into a report as they would like to see each individual one-time with their donation amounts.

I did some research thought maybe I could try to achieve this using a listagg function, but I do not believe you can use an aggregate function this way as group functions aren't allowed.

```
select listagg('DESG: '|| adbdesg_name as "Desg_Name" ||' AMT: $' ||    sum(AGVGLST_AMT), ',') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AGVGLST_GIFT_DATE) "DesgHC2015"
```

Any suggestions/tips would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your query in another query that will do the aggregation:

```
SELECT listagg( total, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY adbdesg_name) AS DesgHC2015
FROM   (
  select ad1.adbdesg_name,
         'DESG: '|| ad1.adbdesg_name || ' AMT: $' || sum(ag1.agvglst_amt) as total
  from   agvglst ag1
         INNER JOIN adbdesg ad1
         ON ag1.agvglst_desg = ad1.adbdesg_desg
  where  ag1.agvglst_pidm = 12345
  and    EXTRACT( YEAR FROM ag1.agvglst_gift_date ) = 2015
  group by ad1.adbdesg_name
)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was needing! I had tried this but I did it backwards. Thank you!

Comment: I also wanna thank you for using the EXTRACT function. I had completely forgotten about it tbh

Answer (score 0):

LISTAGG will merge column values from multiple rows and you can use it in this case, but from what I can see you want to have this first

```
SELECT 'DESG: '|| adbdesg_name || ' AMT: $' ||  Total_amt as Descg_name FROM yourtable
```

This way you will get the columns merged and now you can use listagg like this :

```
SELECT LISTAGG( Descg_name,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY AGVGLST_GIFT_DATE) 
FROM yourtable
```

Note: The values in the order by clause from WITHING GROUP act like a joining key between the result rows.